# Connect Azure Cosmos DB (Postgres) with Azure AI Services Data Source

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I'm struggling with the task of connecting an Azure Cosmos DB (Postgres) to an Azure AI Search Service Data Source.

Here you can see the overview of the Azure Cosmos DB account (as you can also see, there is no entry for keys).
[image]

Now, I want to add a data source here...

[image]

Your account name: This should be "gptplaygroundcosmosdb-c"
your account key: I've read in other Microsoft tutorials for NoSQL databases in Cosmos DB that this should be the key of the Cosmos DB account. However, I can't find any keys there. I've also tried using the keys of the Search Service, which didn't work.

[image]

Can anyone help here so that I can connect the Postgres Cosmos DB with the Cognitive Search data source, allowing me to populate an indexer with data from the Postgres DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing from Postgres is not supported directly.

You will have to either use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql?tabs=data-factory) to copy the data to Blob Storage and use an [Azure Blob indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-storage-integration) or create your own indexing pipeline, for example using something like [Event processing] https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/event-processing-with-azure-database-for-postgresql-and-azure-event-grid-integration/ and the [Push API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-data-import) to send the data directly to the AI search index.

The data sources that are supported are in the [data sources gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/AZURE/search/search-data-sources-gallery).